# How to encrypt password in python?

Tags: python, passwords

I am writing a python script to login in my email, and I am using

`M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')`

`M.login('foo@gmail.com','123456')`

however i want to let my friend use my script but i dont want him to know my password. I was wondering that is this possible?

Comment: Can you use hash functions?

Comment: is it safe to use hash functions?

Answer (score 3):

In general, no this isn't possible, especially not if the idea is for your friend to run the script on their own computer. Your script needs to have access to the plaintext password in order to send it to the server. Whatever obfuscations you apply, anyone with access to run the script can do the same de-obfuscating as the script itself in order to retrieve it. If they have access to modify the script, they could even just change it to print exactly what you send to the server.

The only possible way around this is for you to control the full execution environment, and have the script run with different permissions than the user who can invoke it (using something like setuid Unix permissions, or even something as fully fledged as polkit). This is probably a prohibitive amount of effort compared to what you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry but i am bit confused. Suppose that I can use c++ to achieve the same goal, then I could compile my source file to a.exe and then send to my friend that executive. is there any python equivalent for this?

Comment: @ZhangYifan Even in that case, it is possible to recover the password from the binary using, for example, the `strings` command or a hex editor.

Comment: how about that the password is not explicitly showed? for example i can write a strange function whose return value is the password

Answer (score 0):

```
ema=input("Enter your mail adress: ")
passw=input("Enter your password: ")
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
M.login('{}'format(ema),'{}'.format(passw))
```

Instead of encrypt, you can use this. So your friend not have to see your password, he should enter his mail-password or you either. Or you can use [getpass.getpass()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass)

Comment: im trying to let my friend login to my email instead of his :( and i dont want him to know the password